# Using PHP to get initials of names with 4 letters of last name

Tags: php, preg-match-all, implode, array-map

I have a small bit of code that I'm using to output the initials of a group of names:

```
$names = array("Tom Hanks", "Julia Roberts");
    
    $initials = implode('/', array_map(function ($name) { 
        preg_match_all('/\b\w/', $name, $matches);
        return implode('', $matches[0]);
    }, $names));
    

    echo $initials ;
```

This outputs `TH/JR`.  But what I would prefer is `THank/JRobe` where the first 4 letters of the last name are used.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use string functions.  These work for the types of names you show.  These obviously won't for *John Paul Jones* or *Juan Carlos De Jesus* etc. depending on what you want for them:

```
$initials = implode('/', array_map(function ($name) { 
    return $name[0] . substr(trim(strstr($name, ' ')), 0, 4);
}, $names));
```

- `$name[0]` is the first character
- `strstr` return the space and everything after the space, `trim` the space
- `substr` return the last 4 characters

Optionally, `explode` on the space:

```
$initials = implode('/', array_map(function ($name) { 
    $parts = explode(' ', $name);
    return $parts[0][0] . substr($parts[1], 0, 4);
}, $names));
```

For the `preg_match`:

```
$initials = implode('/', array_map(function ($name) { 
    preg_match('/([^ ]) ([^ ]{4})/', $name, $matches);
    return $matches[1].$matches[2];
}, $names));
```

- `([^ ])` capture not a space
- match a space
- `([^ ]{4})` capture not a space 4 times

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the names consist of word characters, another option for the gives examples could be using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and pass it the array of strings.

The pattern `([A-Z])\w+\h+(\w{4})\w*` uses 2 capture groups where the first group contains an uppercase char and the second group contains 4 word chars which will be used as the replacement.

```
$names = array("Tom Hanks", "Julia Roberts");
echo implode('/', 
    preg_replace(
        "/([A-Z])\w+\h+(\w{4})\w*/",
        "$1$2",
        $names
    )
);
```

Output

```
THank/JRobe
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Fojg7)

To match unicode upper and lowercase characters, the part of the pattern could look like

```
"/(\p{Lu})\p{Ll}+\h+(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{3})\p{L}*/u"
```

Comment: Bravo, I wasn't thinking replace.  Much better than match and build.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think there are mulitple ways to solve it, each with their own fragility due to matching names :-) Have an upvote from me +1